# all-proto-files-under doesn't work on android.mk

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, protocol-buffers, ndk-build

Searching on several projects, I found this line on their android.mk `$(call all-proto-files-under, $(src_proto))`, and I tried to use this like that:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := my_test
src_proto := $(LOCAL_PATH)/proto

LOCAL_CPP_EXTENSION := .cxx .cpp .cc
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS += -std=c++11

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := main.cc \
                   $(call all-proto-files-under, $(src_proto))

# print the source files
$(warning $(LOCAL_SRC_FILES))

# print only main.cc
$(warning $(LOCAL_SRC_FILES))

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/proto

# for logging
LOCAL_LDLIBS    += -llog

# for native asset manager
LOCAL_LDLIBS    += -landroid

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

But it doesn't work, the warning prints nothing, and the second warning prints only main.cc, the line `$(call all-proto-files-under, $(src_proto))` does nothing. I would like to know how can I use protobuf with android ndk.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to solve it with the `all-proto-files-under` function specifically, but if you want to add all source files in a directory you can do that in the following way:

```
PROTOBUF_FILES := $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/proto/*.cc)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(PROTOBUF_FILES:$(LOCAL_PATH)/%=%)
```

I suppose you could simplify that into a oneliner if you wanted to. It's also possible to add all source files in all subdirectories under a given directory if you need that:

```
PROTOBUF_FILES := $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/proto/**/*.cc)
```

---

When I built protobuf myself, I just took [the corresponding `Android.mk` file from the AOSP git](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/protobuf.git/+/master/Android.mk) and removed all the stuff I didn't need.

Comment: I got build protobuf using a shell script that I found, it generates two lib, a full and a lite, but I can't use the lite, only the full, when I try link with the lite I have link problems, were you able to use the lite?

Comment: No, because I needed RTTI to be enabled for protobuf in my project, so I built the `libprotobuf-cpp-full-gnustl-rtti` module from the Android.mk file I linked to.